# Compiler Error CS-1939

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

This code throws Compiler Error CS1939

[Compiler Details : Microsoft Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.34209]

[Visual Studio Version : Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition]

```
public class Program
{
    public static string F(ref int i)
    {
        string[] names= {"test","test2","test3"};

        return names[i];
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var q = from x in list
                let k = x
                select new TempData()
                 {
                     temp=Program.F(ref x)
                };


    }
}

public class TempData 
{
   public string temp;
}
```

This code  does not throw Compiler Error CS1939

[Compiler Details : Microsoft Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.34209]

[Visual Studio Version : Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition]

```
 var languages = from lang in CultureManager.SupportedCultures
                        select new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Value = GetTestLanguageBasedUrl(filterContext, defaultLanguage, ref lang),
                            Text = GetTextByKey(lang.Key.Substring(0, 2)),
                            Selected = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(lang.Key.Substring(0, 2), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        };

private string GetTestLanguageBasedUrl(ActionExecutingContext filterContext, string defaultLanguage, ref KeyValuePair<string, CultureInfo> lang)
{
    if (!defaultLanguage.Equals(lang.Key.Substring(0, 2)))
    {
        if (!filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("culture"))
            filterContext.RouteData.Values.Add("culture", lang.Key.Substring(0, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        if (filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("culture"))
            filterContext.RouteData.Values.Remove("culture");

    }
    var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
    if (nameValues != null && nameValues.Count > 0)
    {
        return Url.RouteUrl(filterContext.RouteData.Values) + "?" + nameValues.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return Url.RouteUrl(filterContext.RouteData.Values);
    }

}
```

We got to know about this issue when we upgraded the Visual Studio 2012 profession to Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and compiled 
the same code but this time compiler reported CS-1939 error. 
Here are the compiler details

[Compiler : MS Visual C# Compiler version 1.2.0.60317]

[Visual Studio Edition: Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise]

Therefore we would like to know why this error is not getting thrown in second block of code.

Comment: Read this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545970.aspx

Comment: Have went thru this link , we now the error details, question is why second block of code is working whereas first block of code is throwing the Error.

Comment: Let's call it progress.  There is no point whatsoever in declaring the argument *ref*, value types whose value isn't modified should be passed by value.  So just fix your code.

Comment: Question is not about logic